# Redrawing or recalculating the width of a Datatable(s) inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am currently using a [Datatable](https://datatables.net/) inside a bootstrap modal.

The data from the datatable comes from a database via ajax.

So far I have been using the method below to create the table inside the modal.

```
$('#searchModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
 var table = $("#searchProdTable").DataTable();
 table.draw();

})
```

The reason I use the above lines of code is because I want to prevent such a event from happening:
Where the width of the datatable exceeds the space of the modal.

[image]

I just realised that this method does not work consistently though.Currently, I have developed that datatable such that it can show different number of columns determined at 'run time'. Thus I am guessing that I should not write down a fixed width for the datatable or modal? Or Should I create a very large modal that is able to fit in any size of the datatable ?

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="searchModal" role="dialog">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Search for Inventory</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="searchProdTable" class="display"></table>


        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: share your html code also or create js fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of Bootstrap you are using, if you are happy with having a horizontal scrollbar within your modal, then you will be able to resolve this by adding `overflow-x: scroll` to the element with the `modal-body` class.

Are you able to share a code snippet, and version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: boostrap version I am using is v3.3.7

Comment: Can you try adding the following into your CSS:

`.modal-body {
   overflow-x: scroll;
}`

Or alternatively, define a new CSS class with above value and assign it to the `modal-body` element:

`.modal-custom-body {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}`

`<div class="modal-body modal-custom-body">
  <table id="searchProdTable" class="display"></table>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the situation occurring in your table: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/RJYZQQ

A solution is, to add below div before your table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/gKdGrE

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DataTable api

```
$(function()) {
    $('#searchModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#searchProdTable").DataTable()
                             .columns.adjust()
                             .responsive.recalc();
    });   
}
```

More [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc())

Comment: I tried your method, and the datatable straight away becomes responsive(the first column has the plus sign upon clicked, to show 2 more columns). However even though 2 columns are hidden nicely, there are still 2 columns at the right side that exceeds the modal width. Does that means I should add in the horizontal scroll as suggested by others?

Comment: that means it is also a CSS issue, I'm not an expert on it, but probably the modal body dimensions are hard to calculate; maybe something with `position` and `width/height`